# HTML Signature Script Issues

Tags: outlook, scripting

I am trying to create a signature script to create a HTML signature across my entire company. Everything about the script seems to work, it creates the signature exactly how marketing wants it. However, when I send an email to anyone, the logos do not appear on their end. My scripting is very limited, so I don't know how to fix this. I've seen something with attaching the image and using the "CID" to get it in, but I don't know how to use this in my script. Below is my script (with some modifications for privacy sake), can anyone help me write this so that the logos would work? I'll owe you a beer for sure!

```
On Error Resume Next

'Setting up the script to work with the file system.
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Connecting to Active Directory to get user’s data.
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set UserObj = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
strAppData = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
SigFolder = StrAppData & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
SigFile = SigFolder & UserObj.sAMAccountName & "1.htm"

'Setting placeholders for the signature.
strUserName = UserObj.sAMAccountName
strFullName = UserObj.displayname
strTitle = UserObj.title
strMobile = UserObj.mobile
strEmail = UserObj.mail
strCompany = UserObj.company
strOfficePhone = UserObj.telephoneNumber

'Setting global placeholders for the signature. Those values will be identical for all users - make sure to replace them with the right values!
strCompanyLogo = "file_location\image.jpg"
strCompanyAddress1 = "Address"
strWebsite = """URL"
strFacebook = """url"
strTwitter = """url"
strYouTube = """url"
strLinkedIn = """url"
strInstagram = """url"
strPinterest = """url"

'Creating HTM signature file for the user's profile, if the file with such a name is found, it will be overwritten.
Set CreateSigFile = FileSysObj.CreateTextFile (SigFile, True, True)

'Signature’s HTML code.
CreateSigFile.WriteLine "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC " & """-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" & """>"
CreateSigFile.WriteLine "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Email Signature</TITLE>"
CreateSigFile.WriteLine "<META content=" & """text/html; charset=utf-8" & """ http-equiv=" & """Content-Type" & """>"
CreateSigFile.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
CreateSigFile.WriteLine "<BODY style=" & """font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;" & """>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<table style=" & """width: 640px; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;" & """ cellpadding=" & """0" & """ cellspacing=" & """0" & """>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<tbody>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<tr>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<td width=" & """130" & """ style=" & """font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; border-right: .5px solid; border-right-color: #404040; width: 115px; padding-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle;" & """ valign=" & """middle" & """ rowspan=" & """6" & """> <a href=" & strWebsite & """ target=" & """_blank" & """><img border=" & """0" & """ alt=" & """Logo" & """ width=" & """96" & """ style=" & """width:96px; height:97px; border:0;" & """ src=" & strCompanyLogo & """></a>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "</td>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<td>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<table cellpadding="& """0"& """ cellspacing="& """0"& """>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<tbody>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<tr>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<td style="& """font-size: 10pt; color:#404040; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; width: 305px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 20px; vertical-align: top; line-height:25px;"& """ valign="& """top"& """>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<strong><span style="& """font-size: 14pt; font-family: Livory Bold, sans-serif; color:#404040;"& """>" & strFullName & "<br></span></strong>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<span style="& """font-family: Livory Regular, sans-serif; font-size:12pt; font-style: italic; color:#404040;"& """>" & strTitle & "</span>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "</td>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "</tr>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<tr>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<td style="& """font-size: 12pt; color:#404040; font-family: Livory Bold, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 20px; vertical-align: top;"& """ valign="& """top"& """>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<span><span style="& """color: #404040;"& """><strong>email </strong></span><span style="& """font-size: 12pt; font-family: Livory Regular, sans-serif; color:#404040;"& """>" & strEmail & "<br></span></span>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<span><span style="& """color: #404040;"& """><strong>phone </strong></span><span style="& """font-family: Livory Regular, sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:#4040404;"& """>" & strOfficePhone & "</span>"
If NOT (strMobile = "") Then 
    CreateSigFile.Writeline "<span style="& """font-family: Livory Bold, sans-serif; font-size:12pt; font-weight: bold; color:#404040;"& """> | mobile </span>"
    CreateSigFile.Writeline "<span style="& """font-family: Livory Regular, sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:#404040;"& """>" & strMobile & "</span>"
End If
CreateSigFile.Writeline "</td>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "</tr>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<tr>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<td style="& """font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 20px; vertical-align: top; color: #0079ac;"& """ valign="& """top"& """>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<span style="& """font-size: 12pt; font-family: Livory Regular, sans-serif; color: #404040;"& """>" & strCompanyAddress1 & "<span><br></span></span>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<span style="& """font-size: 12pt; font-family: Livory Regular, sans-serif; color: #404040;"& """>" & strCompanyAddress2 &"</span>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "</td>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "</tr>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<tr>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<td style="& """font-size: 12pt; font-family: Jabara, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 20px; vertical-align: top; color: #404040;"& """ valign="& """top"& """>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<a href="& "Website URL"& """ target="& """_blank"& """ rel="& """noopener"& """ style="& """text-decoration:none;"& """><span style="& """font-size: 12pt; font-family: Jabara, sans-serif; color: #404040;"& """>website url&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span>"& "<span><a href="& strFacebook & """ target="& """_blank"& """ rel="& """noopener"& """><img border="& """0"& """ width="& """25"& """ margin-left="& """25"& """ alt="& """facebook icon"& """ style="& """border:0; height:25px; width:25px; margin-left:25px"& """ src="& """File Location\facebook.jpg"& """></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="& strLinkedIn & """ target="& """_blank"& """ rel="& """noopener"& """><img border="& """0"& """ width="& """25"& """ alt="& """linkedin icon"&""" style="& """border:0; height:25px; width:25px"& """ src="& """File Location\linkedin.jpg"& """></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="& strInstagram & """ target="& """_blank"& """ rel="& """noopener"& """><img border="& """0"& """ width="& """27"& """ alt="& """instagram icon"& """ style="& """border:0; height:27px; width:27px"& """ src="& """File Location\instagram.jpg"& """></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="& strPinterest & """ target="& """_blank"& """ rel="& """noopener"& """><img border="& """0"& """ width="& """25"& """ alt="& """pinterest icon"& """ style="& """border:0; height:25px; width:25px"& """ src="& """File Location\Pinterest.jpg"& """></a></span>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "</td>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "</tr>"
CreateSigFile.Writeline "<tr>"
CreateSigFile.Close

'Applying the signature in Outlook’s settings.
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objSignatureObjects = objWord.EmailOptions.EmailSignature

'Setting the signature as default for new messages.
objSignatureObjects.NewMessageSignature = strUserName & "1"

'Setting the signature as default for replies & forwards.
objSignatureObjects.ReplyMessageSignature = strUserName & "1"
objWord.Quit
```

Comment: When you inspect the HTML on the recipient side (you can look at raw MIME source in Gmail), does `img` tag still point to a local folder instead of using cid to link to an attachment?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I believe it is still pointing to a local or network folder. I don't know how to use cid to link to an attachment within my script, do you know how I could write the code to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at existing signatures with images - Outlook stores images in a subfolder of the Signatures folder and the `img` tag refers to images using a relative path. When a signature is inserted, Outlook adds images as attachments and replaces the relative references in the HTML body with the cid references that refer to attachments based on their content-id.

If you images are referenced using absolute path, they will not be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up storing the logos within our word press server and referencing them there. Some mail clients won't necessarily load the logos without trusting the sender, but my boss and marketing team had no issues with that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).